# Ruby dup method for ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Can someone explain me this behaviour of AR object:

```
u = User.first
uu = u.dup

uu == u  #=> true
u == uu  #=> false
```

Why is the latter not true?

Comment: Running this I get `false` for both. (Which is the correct result, by the way.)

Comment: I use ruby 1.9.3-p0 and rails 3.0.11. And of course, it should be `false` in both cases on logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because [`ActiveRecord::Base#==`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.9/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-3D-3D) returns `false` if the second object is a new record. Since `uu.new_record?` is `true`, when doing `u == uu` it returns `false`; but `u.new_record?` is `false`, so `uu == u` does not fail that check.

This behavior has changed since Rails 3.0 and both `u == uu` and `uu == u` will return `false` in Rails 3.2 (and possibly 3.1).

Answer (score 0):

I get false for both when I run this on `Ruby 1.9.3p194` and `Rails 3.2.3`, so I can only assume it was a bug that was fixed.

As for *why* did it happen in the first place, my theory is that the duplicated record remembers where it came from, and therefore knew to return true when compared to the original. The original holds no such information, and therefore doesn't know how to recognize it's clones.

Comment: thanks, i thought the same way at first. Now i checked on 'Rails 3.2.1' and got 'false' for both too. Interesting, it's a bug, or, maybe, my project/environment bad settings

Comment: A duplicated object knows nothing about its "original" object.